# how to multiply 2 text box values with javascript and ouput the answer to a 3rd textbox that is a ko.observable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage that has multiple textboxes inside of a table. I need to take a value from one textbox and multiply it with another textbox then display that answer to a third text box that is a ko.observable. I have written the below javascript and I cannot get it to work at all. Absolutely nothing happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function calculateLineTotal(numunit, rate, total) {
    var rate = document.getElementById(rate).value;
    var numunit = document.getElementById(numunit).value;


    var sum = numunit * rate;


    document.getElementById(total).value = sum;

}
```

and the corresponding HTML:

```
 <td><input class="text"  type="number" name="NumUnit1" id="NumUnit1" value="0.00" onchange="calculateLineTotal('NumUnit1','Rate1','Total1')"/></td>
                <td><input class="text"  type="number" name="Rate1" id="Rate1" value="0.00" onchange="calculateLineTotal('NumUnit1','Rate1','Total1')"/></td>

                <td><input data-bind="value: total1" type="number" class="text" name="Total1" id="Total1" value="0.00"/></td>
```

I have tried single just simplifying the function to just throw an alert when the first textbox value is changed and nothing even happens then. Again I am a javascript newb so please be kind. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have a misspelling `caclulateLineTotal` should be `calculateLineTotal`. what error does your debugger give?

Comment: Nice catch! So that definitely made the call itself work! Wow I feel like a moron. Thank you. However, now I am getting a new error.  When I enter a value into the first textbox and then switch to the next textbox it says, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null , in the debugger.

Comment: see my solution, that shows a somewhat more clean approach. One of your big issues now is having the same variable name on the right and left hand side, especially for `total`. The second `getElementById(total)` line is going to pass the "number" value as you set it on the line `var total = document.getElementById(total).value;`

Comment: You should find and fix spelling errors in your code before asking. You'll learn more by solving it yourself.

Comment: Thank you JK, but as I am sure all of you are aware, after you have stared at code for almost 18 hours straight everything starts to get by you. I truly do appreciate everyone's help and input. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the text box is bound to a `ko.observable`, i.e. you are using KnockoutJS. So a *much* cleaner way to do this would be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="text" type="number" data-bind="value: numUnit1" /></td>
        <td><input class="text" type="number" data-bind="value: rate1" /></td>

        <td><input class="text" type="number" data-bind="value: total1" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then as the corresponding view model:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.numUnit1 = ko.observable('0.00');
    self.rate1 = ko.observable('0.00');

    self.total1 = ko.computed(function() {
        var total = parseFloat(self.numUnit1()) * parseFloat(self.rate1());

        return total.toFixed(2); // assuming you want to show to 2 decimal places
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mZk42/3/**

Comment: Glad to hear it! Give it a go, any problems let me know. By the way, one of KnockoutJS' strongest points is its [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) – really easy to read, give it a go. Your problem is actually almost identical to [the first Live Example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html) in their docs. (And finally, it sounds like you may have many table rows like this, you could automate them if you're not already, but that would be best suited to a new question if you want it).

Comment: Yes the only way I was able to get as far as I did with Knockout was because of their amazing documentation and live examples. Checkout my JSFiddle of my current Knockout script.  I'm not sure where to implement your suggestion. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9jQr/) Thank you again.

Comment: I have updated my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9jQr/9/) to reflect how I thought it would be implemented. It is not working at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shai, I don't know that I can thank you enough for this!! I finally got it all working like a dream. For anyone that finds this thread later I have updated my [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9jQr/9/) to show the script that I finally ended up with to get this to work. THANK YOU EVERYONE for your generosity and willingness to assist a newb!

Comment: Anyone coming to this later, remember to include the KnockoutJS script itself as an External Resource in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use parseFloat(...), i.e.

```
var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById(rate).value);
var numunit = parseFloat(document.getElementById(numunit).value));


var sum = numunit * rate;
```

Also there is a typo in one call to your function, i.e. "caclulateLineTotal" instead of "calculateLineTotal"

Also, don't set the total variable again, i.e. don't do

```
var total = parseFloat(document.getElementById(total).value);
```

Also, note that your second call to calculateLineTotal, i.e. for element Rate1 is missing a closing ' after Rate1

should be

```
<input class="text"  type="number" name="Rate1" id="Rate1" value="0.00" onchange="calculateLineTotal('NumUnit1','Rate1','Total1');"/>
```

Comment: Does that explain why simplifying the function to just alert("call was successfull") didn't work?

Comment: No... sorry, but you will have to parseFloat anyway, that is what struck me at first. Let me check the other issue. One moment.

Comment: Yes that was pointed out by Victory above. Thank you though. I am still not getting the function to work however. Thank you for your help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: Also you are resetting the total variable in the function

Comment: It is a good idea to keep the debugger/browser console open when working with javascript. You will spot issues like these at once.

Comment: ok so if I use parsefloat as instructed, the function does not work. If I do not use parsefloat it works but only one time. For example if I try to run the function again on another set of text boxes on the same page it says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. Did I say you guys are awesome? If I didn't, You are all AWESOME! Thank you all sooo much for your assistance.

Comment: See my last revision of the answer, that solves the "Unexpected token" issue.

Comment: Perfect!! It now works almost as expected. The 'Total' Textbox is receiving the sum perfectly. However it seems to have broken my ko.observable. Would anyone like to see my Knockout script to see if you can tell why it broke? Or should I post that as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZJb7/4/)

Add class to select on using `querySelectAll` called "changes"

```
<td><input class="changes text"  type="number" name="NumUnit1" id="NumUnit1" value="0.00" /></td>
<td><input class="changes text"  type="number" name="Rate1" id="Rate1" value="0.00" /></td>
<td><input data-bind="value: total1" type="number" class="text" name="Total1" id="Total1" value="0.00"/></td>
```

Use `addEventListener` to bind changes. Run a forloop to add the callback, notice that the function `bindCalculateTotal` returns another function.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input.changes");
var bindCalculateTotal = function (numunitId, rateId, totalId) {
    return function(event) {
        console.log(numunitId, rateId, totalId);
        console.log( document.getElementById(totalId).value);
        var rate = document.getElementById(rateId).value;
        var numunit = document.getElementById(numunitId).value;
        var total = document.getElementById(totalId).value;
        var sum = numunit * rate;
        document.getElementById(totalId).value = sum;
    };
};

for (var ii = 0; ii < inputs.length; ii++) {
     inputs[ii].addEventListener(
         'change', 
         bindCalculateTotal("NumUnit1", "Rate1", "Total1"));
}
```

Also notice how we use "*Id" names to store the value.  That fixes this line

```
  document.getElementById(total).value = sum; // error: total is number, not the id
```